# OpenLayers 3: Dynamically or batch add layers from user folder

Tags: javascript, openlayers, batch, dynamic, array

I would like to dynamically load all layers (KML, for instance) from a user's folder to a group map. This likely requires an iteration that searches the folder and adds the layers to the users' map.

I've been to [here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/drag-and-drop.html) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137964/open-layers-3-dynamically-add-layer-from-folder-contents), but neither of these discuss iterative  layers from a given location, nor how to parse *n* layer names, presumably by `Document.getElementById()`.

Whatever the route taken, list needs to pass to a function I have in a table for creating toggle buttons on each layer.  This code works, just curious as to the iteration's effects.

```
function toggleControl(element){
     if(element.value == "dynamicallyaddedlayer1"){
      dynamicallyaddedlayer1.setVisibility(element.checked);
     }
     if(element.value == "dynamicallyaddedlayer2"){
      dynamicallyaddedlayer2.setVisibility(element.checked);
     }}    
//...... and so on for as many n layers present

<div id="layerpanel">
    <div data-role="field contain" data-type=“vertical” style="text-align:justify;">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" style="margin-top:0px">  
        <input type="checkbox" name=“dynamiclayer1" value="dynamiclayer1btn" id="dynamiclayer1btn" class=".ui-corner-all" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
        <label for="dynamiclayer1btn">Name-of-Dynamically-Added-Layer-#1</label>
//... and so on for as many n layers present
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```